# Knowing the center point of an imageView rotation during animation

Tags: java, android-studio, animation, rotation, game-engine

I've got one rotation animation to rotate one imageView around one fixed position (the center). Now I want to know in every second where the imageView, which rotates, is. In other words the imageView which rotates is a circle and I want to know the center point of this imageView during animation.

This is my code for the rotation:

```
    WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
    Display disp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    disp.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    ImageView circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
    circle.setTranslationX(screenWidth/4);
    RotateAnimation rotation = new RotateAnimation(0, 359, 50f, 50f);
    rotation.setDuration(5000);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    circle.startAnimation(rotation);
```

If I do this, it doesn´t exactly know the location, something else... Could you explain?

```
    ImageView circle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.circle);
    circleX = circle.getX();
    circleY = circle.getY();
    int circleCenterX = (int) circleX + circle.getWidth() / 2;
    int circleCenterY = (int) circleY + circle.getHeight() / 2;
```

Comment: I know, the center point is the first point when the animation starts, but it does not change during animation. How can i fix it?